# pg_dump failed "backup : cache lookup failed"

Tags: postgresql

We had `pg_dump` failed with `"backup : cache lookup failed for type 174104"`.

> 2016-01-06 03:08:46.572
>   EST,"postgres","aabbcc",13840,"[local]",568cf5bd.3610,3,"SELECT",2016-01-06
>   03:08:45 PST,2/24331,0,ERROR,XX000,"cache lookup failed for type
>   174104",,,,,,"SELECT proretset, prosrc, probin,
>   pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(oid) AS funcargs,
>   pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(oid) AS funciargs,
>   pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(oid) AS funcresult, proiswindow,
>   provolatile, proisstrict, prosecdef, proleakproof, proconfig, procost,
>   prorows, (SELECT lanname FROM pg_catalog.pg_language WHERE oid =
>   prolang) AS lanname FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc WHERE oid =
>   '174103'::pg_catalog.oid",,,"pg_dump"

Tried following solutions that not work.
1) bounced DB not work
2) vacuum full not work

Any idea is appreciated :)

Comment: You might try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What file system are you using for your underlying storage may I ask?

Answer (score 0):

3) pg_basebackup worked too

It is local RAID file system.

It did not seem to work after REINDEX of all the tables.
I tried pg_dump of all tables 1-by-1 but did not spot anything weird.